# How can I check for bad sectors of a flash device with C?

Tags: c, file-io, filesystems, hardware, sector

I need to create a utility to check for bad sectors in flash memory.

I started out with an old flash drive that I have, I stuck it in my Ubuntu laptop and checked the `dmesg` to see it was mounted as `/dev/sdb`, I then ran `fdisk` to see the number/size of the sectors:

> mike@mike-Qosmio-X770:~$ sudo fdisk -l [sudo] password for mike:
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 127 MB, 127926272 bytes 16 heads, 32 sectors/track, 488
>   cylinders, total 249856 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512
>   bytes
>  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>  I/O size
>   (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>  Disk identifier: 0x6b3ee723
>
> ```
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System 
> /dev/sdb1   *     32         249854     124911+   b  W95 FAT32
> ```

So great, I know a sector is 512 bytes and there should be a total of 249,856 of them. Based on that I wrote this small test program to double check:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE * fp = NULL;
    char buffer[512] = {0};  // size of a sector, 512 bytes
    long sector_count = 0;

     fp = fopen("/dev/sdb", "rb");  // open the flash device as binary

    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open the flash drive!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    while(!feof(fp) && (fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp) > 0)){
         sector_count++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Sectors: %ld\n", sector_count);
    return 0;
}
```

Worked wonderfully, reported 249856. Now I'm stuck thinking how to proceed. Would it work to write a series of `0xFF`'s to the drive (512x249856 `1` bit's), then read it back to make sure it got set to 1? Then write the same number of `0`s to make sure it can  be cleared?

Would that verify that everything's working? Is there any chance I could overwrite the FTL (Flash translation layer) code or is that protected even from me messing around with the drive like this?

`<background for interested parties>`
This is for a project where we have a uCLinux 2.4 kernel with strange behavior.. we suspect bad hardware (specificly the flash) but I can't find good tools that work on 2.4 to test the flash fs so I thought I'd try to write my own.
`</background>`

Comment: *Why* do you want to create something like this from scratch? There are lots of tools like this around, e.g. `badblocks` for Linux...

Comment: @thkala - Can you please name one that works on 2.4 kernel with uCLinux (micro C Linux). If I don't have to make one I won't.

Comment: for one, you should be able to replicate the functionality of such a program with basic tools... `dd` and `cmp` come to mind. Then there is `badblocks` from the `e2fsprogs` package - you could try using an older version if the newer ones complain about your host environment...

Comment: As a matter of fact, for a simple read test `dd` and possibly `wc` would be sufficient. Just run `dd if=/dev/mtd13 of=- | wc -c` and verify that the byte count reported by `wc` is equal to the size of `/dev/mtd13`...

Comment: If that works fine, then you can use `dd` to write something else to the device and then `cmp` to read back and compare. Does the flash device contain your root filesystem? Do you have other storage devices on your system? Something to use for temporary storage?

Comment: By the way, 512-byte block operation on a flash device? Not a very good idea if you are going to do any writes. I would suggest finding the erase/write block size for your flash and using the largest of the two...

Comment: @thkala - `I would suggest finding the erase/write block size for your flash` any idea on how to go about doing that? I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: I suppose the Linux kernel might be reporting that somehow, but I don't actually know where. A safer way might be to find out which flash chip your device is using and read its datasheet. In any case, using a multiple of the block size should be safe - it's *smaller* writes that wear out the chip unnecessarily. You could even use the size of the whole MTD device as the block size, if you have enough memory.

Comment: @thkala - Thanks for all the input before. I Got a chance to check my system today, none of the tools: `dd`, `cmp`, `wc`, `badblocks`, nor `e2fsprogs` exist on the system. So I'll either have to find the source for these and recompile them for the coldfire toolchain, or make my own. (I want to avoid rebuilding the whole kernel as not to mess with my current setup) Know where to get the source off hand?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that since your device is mounted on `/dev/sdb1` we're dealing with some kind of removable flash media device such as a USB-stick or media-card.  If you are dealing with an SATA attached SSD, similar considerations apply.

In these devices, the block-interface is an abstraction for a complex device controller that sits on top of the flash.

Flash devices typically have very large blocks (called erase units, 128kB is not uncommon as a size) which can be written once before a much slower erase takes place.   The device's controller implements a logical<->physical mapping between the block interface - as seen by the host - and erase-units on the physical device.   As part of the management process, the controller will implemented error detection and correction and manage defective erase units.   This entire process is invisible at the block interface.

Consequently, as logical blocks never have a permanent mapping to physical erase units, it is impossible to perform a meaningful bad-block scan from the block-interface.

If you happen to have a directly attached flash array managed by the `mtd` layer, `mtd-tools` is what you want, along with the corresponding kernel-modules.  Documentation can be found [here](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/faq/general.html)

Comment: I was under the impression that the OP was only using `/dev/sdX` as a testbed. If they are indeed using a USB or SATA device, wouldn't it be simpler to just take it out and test it on a full-blown computer?

Comment: Yes, @thkala is correct the `/dev/sdb` device was just a testbed. In regards to your point about `mtd-tools` I did look at that but they don't work: `"The 2.4 kernel does not have NAND support in JFFS2, and will not have anything but high-priority bug-fixes applied to it."` I've got a 2.4kernel with a NAND flash chip.

Comment: so what precisely *is* your hardware setup and what drivers and filing systems are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

Modern hardware can usually recognize data corruption, i.e. you are more likely to encounter an I/O error than actually reading bad data from a device. Furthermore, the devices usually contain some amount of redundancy, so bad blocks will be detected and replaced with good ones. For modern hard discs, [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) will give information on the bad block count. Not sure whether this works for common flash devices as well, but I'd guess so.